# Calendar Event via Intent does not set Start Date and End Date

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have stucked in problem that start date and end date is not setting in calendar event please let me know whats the problem is here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

 myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
 myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
 myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
 myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
 myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

 Log.d("endtime", myCalendar.getTime().toString());
 intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
 intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
 intent.putExtra("endTime", myCalendar.getTime().toString());
 intent.putExtra("title", data.getTitle());
 startActivity(intent);
```

Log
D/endtime: Thu Apr 13 12:00:00 GMT+05:00 2017
But it doesn't set in calender

Here is a screen shot please have a look

[Calender Image with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG6Z0.png)

Comment: You never set start time

Comment: Can you put the code u use to set calender back to view?

Comment: but i set end time

Comment: http://freecs13.hostei.com/pic.png

Comment: I think you should use "dtstart" and "dtend" keys instead. Please check also the CalendarContract.Events class. Please use those values instead of the hardcoded String: CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART.

Comment: "dtstart" and "dtend" keys are not working. Problem still remain